# Setting the assembly name for a web application project

Tags: asp.net

How do you set the assembly name for a web application project?

The following page in the MSDN document says ‘Because this compilation model creates a single assembly, you can specify attributes, such as assembly name and version’. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983464.aspx.

However I can’t work out how you can do this!

Comment: Try going to Project Properties

Comment: Thanks - I don't know how I missed this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select Properties.  On the Application tab, there's an Assembly Name text box, where you can set that.